# Reading RDF data in the N-Triples format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, rdf

I am trying to execute the example of the rdf gem see [here](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf/blob/develop/README.md)

Code I try to execute:

```
   require 'rdf'
   include RDF
   require 'rdf/ntriples'
   graph = RDF::Graph.load("http://ruby-rdf.github.com/rdf/etc/doap.nt")
```

I got the following error:

```
/home/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri.rb:96:in `<top (required)>': URI is not a module (TypeError)
from /home/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/util/file.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rdf-1.1.4.2/lib/rdf/reader.rb:136:in `open'
from rdf_foaf.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

My setup:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
rvm 1.25.28 (stable)

rdf (1.1.4.2)
rdf-aggregate-repo (1.1.0)
rdf-isomorphic (1.1.0)
rdf-json (1.1.0)
rdf-microdata (1.1.1.3)
rdf-n3 (1.1.1)
rdf-rdfa (1.1.3.2)
rdf-rdfxml (1.1.0.1)
rdf-trig (1.1.3.1)
rdf-trix (1.1.0)
rdf-turtle (1.1.4)
rdf-xsd (1.1.1)
```

As the error seems to come from uri.rb I do not know how to handle it.
Who has hints to solve this issue?

Comment: It looks like you or one of your gems has defined something for the top level `URI`. Can you post your `rdf_foaf.rb` file, or put `require 'net/http'` at the top of your script and let us know what happens?

Comment: require 'net/http' seems to solve the issue thank you very much! The error message we also assumed that it has something to do with top level URI but had no clue how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `include RDF` in your script, you make `RDF::URI` accessible with `URI`. Your error makes it seem like this namespacing also applies in required files. I'm not super familiar with how Ruby handles `include` in cases like this (I try to avoid "polluting" the global namespace and generally only use `include` inside class definitions).

In any case, the `include RDF` line can be omitted here, since you use the full reference for `RDF::Graph`.

The call to `require 'net/http'` makes it work because it loads `URI` before `RDF::URI` class can claim that name.